# how to bind local image to the image view using ReactiveKit?

Tags: ios, swift, reactivekit

For fetching image from server I have done this

```
// fetch image from server
    func fetchImage(url: NSURL) -> Operation<UIImage, NSError> {
        return Operation { observer in

            // use almofire to deal with server request
            let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, url).response { request, response, data, error in

                // if error occurs then abort the operation
                if let error = error {
                    observer.failure(error)
                } else {
                    // if doesnt occurs error then convert imageData back to image
                    if(data != nil)
                    {
                        observer.next(UIImage(data : data!)!)
                        observer.success()
                    }
                }
            }

            // if response is nil then execute this block
            return BlockDisposable {
                request.cancel()
            }
        }

    }
```

& then bind it to the image view

```
if (url != nil)
        {
            let image : ObservableBuffer<UIImage>? = self.fetchImage(url!).shareNext()

            if ((image) != nil)
            {

                image!.bindTo(customCellObj.mContentCellImageView)
            }
        }
```

Here I am fetching image from url using almofire. Is there any way by which I can bind local DB image with an image view directly using reactive kit?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you connect an imageView to your stream:

```
    Stream.just(NSURL(string: "https://exoticcars.enterprise.com/etc/designs/exotics/clientlibs/dist/img/homepage/Homepage-Hero-Car.png")!)
        .flatMapLatest(fetchImage)
        .flatMapError { _ in return Stream.just(UIImage()) }
        .observeNext { [weak self] image in self?.imageView.image = image }
        .disposeIn(bag)
```

However, at the risk of sounding way too obvious... That's what ReactiveUIKit is for.

```
    Stream.just(NSURL(string: "https://exoticcars.enterprise.com/etc/designs/exotics/clientlibs/dist/img/homepage/Homepage-Hero-Car.png")!)
        .flatMapLatest(fetchImage)
        .flatMapError { _ in return Stream.just(UIImage()) }
        .bindTo(imageView.rImage)
        .disposeIn(bag)
```

Also there is an Alamofire extension to ReactiveKit (AlamofireReactive) that you might find useful.